# How to add custom text to the footer of an MVC telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I am using the telerik MVC grid extension in my MVC2 application, and I would like to add a custom piece of text (a record count) in the footer. I don't want to use paging in this particular case.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is nothing built-in which you can use. We will be adding footer templates in our next release. Till then you can try some jQuery magic to inject the required HTML:

```
$('#Grid').find('.t-grid-footer').append("some HTML")
```

Comment: When is the next release due out? The target for this website is a smart phone, and the javascript doesn't seem to be very reliable :(

Comment: The next release is due November. As a last resort you can always modify the source code to add the required info in the footer.

Comment: I think I can wait until it's officially in there. I'd love to have the time to add it myself to the source and submit a patch for consideration to go into the next release. But, I don't have the spare time :(